# Change field when 2 conditions met

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a timesheet database and need to change TypeOfPay in the following example

If a person gets paid for a Stat Holiday (TypeOfPay = Stat Holiday) and also worked on that day (TypeOfPay = regular), change all lines to TypeOfPay = Stat In.

1. Date        Description  Employee  TypeOfPay     TimeSpent
2. 2016-09-05  ABC_Company  BobJones  Stat Holiday  8.00
3. 2016-09-05  BCD_Company  BobJones  regular       1.25
4. 2016-09-05  Lift_Check   BobJones  regular       0.25

Thanks in advance
Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple update. You join the table to itself using the conditions you supplied (same date, holiday vs regular, and same employee)  and update the type of pay. 
You can see the correlation by just doing the join without the update.

```
select * 
from #Timesheet t
left join #Timesheet holiday on t.date = holiday.date and t.employee = holiday.employee and t.typeofPay = 'regular' and holiday.typeofpay = 'Stat Holiday'
```

This is the table setup I used. obviously you will replace #Timesheet with whatever your actual table name is

```
create table #Timesheet
(
[Date] Date not null,
[Description] varchar(20) null,
[Employee] varchar(30) not null,
[TypeOfPay] varchar(12) null,
[TimeSpent] Numeric (12,2) null
)
Insert into #Timesheet 
(Date,Description, Employee, TypeOfPay, TimeSpent)
Values
('2016-09-05', 'ABC_Company', 'BobJones', 'Stat Holiday', 8.00),
('2016-09-05', 'BCD_Company', 'BobJones', 'regular' ,1.25),
('2016-09-05', 'Lift_Check', 'BobJones', 'regular', 0.25),
('2016-09-05', 'ABC_Company', 'BobJones', 'Stat Holiday', 8.00), 
('2016-09-05', 'BCD_Company', 'BobJones', 'regular' ,1.25), 
('2016-09-05', 'Lift_Check', 'BobJones', 'regular', 0.25), 
('2016-09-05', 'Lift_Check', 'JoeSmith', 'regular', 0.25), 
('2016-09-06', 'Lift_Check', 'BobJones', 'regular', 0.25)

  update t --(this is your timesheet table)
Set t.TypeOfPay = 'Stat in' 
from #Timesheet t
inner join #Timesheet holiday on t.date = holiday.date and t.employee = holiday.employee and t.typeofPay = 'regular' and holiday.typeofpay = 'Stat Holiday'
where t.TypeOfPay <> 'Stat Holiday'
```

and you can verify by checking the updated table.

```
select * from #Timesheet
```

Comment: Hi xenapan, thanks for your reply.  What I need is only regular changed to Stat In, not Stat Holiday.  I tried running and making changes, but I'm having difficulty getting the correct answer.  Thanks, Gerry

Comment: what have you tried? Set t.TypeOfPay = 'Stat Holiday'  <- replace holiday with in should do it.

Comment: I added a couple more lines every line changes to Stat In, no matter the date or employee.

Comment: show your code. and explain what shouldnt change and why

Comment: for some reason I cannot add my code as code.  I put in 4 spaces and it doesn't allow it

Comment: For some reason I cannot add as code                                                        ('2016-09-05', 'ABC_Company', 'BobJones', 'Stat Holiday', 8.00),
('2016-09-05', 'BCD_Company', 'BobJones', 'regular' ,1.25),
('2016-09-05', 'Lift_Check', 'BobJones', 'regular', 0.25),
('2016-09-05', 'Lift_Check', 'JoeSmith', 'regular', 0.25),
('2016-09-06', 'Lift_Check', 'BobJones', 'regular', 0.25)

I added a couple lines, from line 1 down the TypeOfPay should be;           Stat Holiday, Stat In, Stat In, regular, regular

Comment: Thanks xenapan, much appreciated